# Switching between silent mode and ring mode on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to switch from silent mode to ring mode (and vice versa) on an iPhone 
programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its against the Human Interface Guidelines according to Apple, so it shouldn't be done, and apps may get rejected for doing it.

Comment: I consider it a feature.  The last thing I want is for an app to switch my phone from silent -> ringer when I didn't ask for it!

Comment: Unless your silent switch is broken. ;)  Then you either never receive calls again, or you toggle it in software (or get a new phone).

Comment: @JasonD Assistive touch can be used to toggle the silent switch.